# What are the similarities and differences between incremental backup and file synchronization?

Tags: backup, sync, file-transfer

Suppose that I have a **source** drive (e.g., internal hard drive) and a **destination** drive (e.g., external hard drive).

### Similarities

- Obviously, they both involve copying files from the source to the destination.
- They both involve copying of new or modified files only, not the entire source (after the initial transfer).

### Differences

- Incremental backup stores all the files, such that if a source file is deleted, the corresponding destination file will [*not* be deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/560256/incremental-backup#comment682538_560266).  On the other hand, in file synchronization the destination mirrors the source, so if a source file is deleted, the corresponding destination file *will* be deleted.

### What are other similarities and differences?

Comment: Sounds to me like homework question...

Comment: It's 1-way vs. 2-way.  Incremental backup copies newer files from source to destination.  Synch also copies newer files on destination to source.  If source and destination contents match and you delete a file from the source, synching will replace it from the destination.  If you add a new file directly to the destination, synching will copy it to the source.

Comment: @MattClark Yes, it does sound like a homework question, but it's truly not. Truly.